# "Could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.XX-generic/modules.dep.bin'" when mounting using a loop

Tags: modprobe

Running 14.04 in virtualbox 4.3.8

Unable to detect the guest additions.iso when i selected the guest additions.iso in the IDE Secondary Master.

No problem, so I used wget and downloaded the iso into the guest ubuntu headless.

when I attempt to load the iso from inside using these commands:

```
sudo mkdir /media/iso
sudo modprobe loop
sudo mount filename.iso /media/iso -t iso9660 -o loop
```

At the `sudo modprobe loop`, I got the following error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/modules.dep.bin'
```

Here are my `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

EDIT:

When I typed

```
ls /lib/modules/*/modules.dep.bin
```

I get back

```
/lib/modules/3.11.0-20-generic/modules.dep.bin  /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/mo‌​dules.dep.bin /lib/modules/3.5.0-49-generic/modules.dep.bin
```

Comment: When I do this I just get 1 dep.bin: `ls /lib/modules/*/modules.dep.bin
/lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/modules.dep.bin
` But somehow he still says I have 4.2.0.25. How might this come?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to Braiam comments, I have solved it using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.13.0
```

Comment: I had the same problem after the battery in my notebook failed during boot. `mo‌​dules.dep.bin` was empty. (computer shut off probably right during rebuild or something?) The mentioned reinstall solved the problem. Thanks! After further study I think it would probably suffice to run `depmod` to regenerate the file.

Answer (score 20):

No need to reinstall linux image

```
sudo depmod
```

works fine for me. credit goes to @pabouk

Comment: The I get: `sudo depmod
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
`

Comment: I have the same error as @kwoxer.

Comment: this worked for me, after notebook lost power, and rebooting it, /boot/efi could not be booted anymore, not even manually...

Comment: `sudo depmod
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/4.9.0/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/4.9.0/modules.builtin: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 9):

It may be system changes waiting for a reboot after updates. My installation was pointing to the wrong `/lib/modules/<version>`, but it worked itself out after a reboot.

```
#:/ $ sudo modinfo iptable_nat
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.1.18+/modules.dep.bin'
modinfo: ERROR: Module alias iptable_nat not found.
```

Comment: I also has this issue: `sudo modinfo iptable_nat
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modinfo: ERROR: Module alias iptable_nat not found.`

Comment: @kwoxer did you try rebooting?

Comment: Was able to solve it already : http://serverfault.com/questions/780980/error-could-not-open-directory-lib-modules-4-2-0-25-generic-no-such-file-or-d/780982

Comment: Thankful for this answer. Saved me from reinstalling linux. :)

Comment: I am writing ansible role for iptables setup and experiencing the same issue.. after reboot all works... but I need to do it in a programmatic way, so no reboot allowed. Is there any way to make it work without reboot?

Comment: @Drew I am not sure. This is a long time ago for me. Please remember to drop the answer off there if you make it work!

Answer (score 5):

```
 # apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-`uname -r`
```

This will do the trick unless you want to upgrade your kernel.

Comment: Same answer as Kim Stacks's earlier one.

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 64 gb really ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case on a raspberry 3b+ running on the raspbian OS, trying to run a `cryptsetup` command which uses dm_mod in the kernel, which was not included in my kernel, this helped without needing a re-flash of the raspberry:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall --yes raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel
sudo reboot
```

Taken from this thread: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=282802

My `cryptsetup` command worked afterwards, while having the same error like OP stated: `Cannot initialize device-mapper. Is dm_mod kernel module loaded?` previously.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, I'm experiencing this issue if I specify an `ExecStart` stanze in a `systemd` unit containing two commands connected with `&&`, e.g.

```
ExecStart=/sbin/modprobe zfs && /usr/local/sbin/zpool import -d /dev data
```

This might be incorrect, but then `systemd` would still need to fail with a helpful error message - like any program ever existing.

The command chain can be expressed with `bash -c`, e.g.

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/sbin/modprobe zfs && /usr/local/sbin/zpool import -d /dev data'
```

(mind the simple quotes `''` instead of double quotes `""`).

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I couldn’t believe it but I got the same error and after much troubleshooting, I’ve discovered that the `/boot` was NOT mounted during this kernel module rebuild.

Once mounted, the problem went away for me.

Turns out that I was a good “victim” of a good security practice (as outlined by CISecurity).

Answer (score -1):

If you can't access the network you can do

```
dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

It worked for me