# USB and Network adapters don't work after Ubuntu 14.04 fresh install. No ethernet, wifi, bluetooth, usb

Tags: wireless, 14.04, usb, intel-wireless

After a failed upgrade from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 ([see](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477370/ubuntu-14-04-boots-to-black-screen-after-upgrade-from-13-10-no-display-proble)), I fresh installed from a life usb. In the test system and in 13.10 usb and all my networks were working out of the box (bluetooth, ethernet, wifi, GSM card). First I ran into a login-loop problem, due to wrong permissions of the .Xauthority file ([see](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)).

Now I have no network adapters and no USB ports at all being recognized.
[My system](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7596717/).

`uname -a` is:

```
Linux lusatia 3.13.0-27-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 15 18:06:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`ifconfig` yields:

```
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:293 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:293 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:21825 (21.8 KB)  TX bytes:21825 (21.8 KB)
```

`iwconfig` yields:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`sudo lshw -C network` gives:

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 96
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f0c00000-f0c01fff
```

`sudo rfkill list` gives no output.

`dpkg -l linux-firmware`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  linux-firmware 1.127.2      all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
```

`sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep     file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep     file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/modules.dep.bin'
 modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/modules.dep.bin'
 modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Function not implemented
```

In my dual boot Windows 7 all network is working fine.

Could that all be a simple problem with some network config file?

Comment: I had a similar problem, at the end I've installed lubuntu 14 and installed over the desktop manager of preference (gnome-shell in my case)

Comment: What kernel are you running? Is there any output at the end of `/var/log/kern.log` when you do do `modprobe iwlwifi`? Do you have linux-firmware installed? (`dpkg -l linux-firmware`)

Comment: Hi muka, so the problem was connected to the desktop manager? I would prefer to stay with ubuntu and make this installation work ..

Comment: @bain, kernel: 3.13.0-27-generic. 
I do have linux firmware installed (Version 1.127.2), I add the output of `dpkg -l linux-firmware` to my original post.
`modprobe iwlwifi` yields an error and adds nothing to kern.log

Comment: What is the modprobe error? There is a slightly later kernel release, if you have wired networking you could update with `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: added the error to my post

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.XX-generic/modules.dep.bin'" when mounting using a loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/459296/could-not-open-moddep-file-lib-modules-3-xx-generic-modules-dep-bin-when-mo)

Comment: Wired network is also not working. But I updated and upgraded everything last night from the life usb test system via mounting my local ubuntu, I can try that again-

Comment: Linked question suggests `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.13.0` - can you try it?

Comment: I did `apt-get dist-upgrade` and the suggested `--reinstall linux-image-3.13.0` from the life usb test system, and networks and USB magically work. Thanks a lot!!!! May I add your comment as correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is fixed after performing `apt-get dist-upgrade` and executing `--reinstall linux-image-3.13.0`, as suggested by bain, from a test ubuntu system of a life usb in which i mounted my local linux installation as root directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know there is already an accepted answer but I found a different solution as the accepted one did not work for me.

I **checked the software updater,** it said the latest update had been downloaded but not installed yet...

After looking through the items to update, I noticed that two of the items were **'ubuntu-core**' and they could not be installed alongside other items due to an untrusted package issue.

So, the solution was to **uncheck all apart from the ubuntu-core** updates, run the install via '**install now'** and **reboot** my machine.

Hey presto, I'm here posting this answer via my usb keyboard as a result!