# Laptop display stopped working with correct resolution for no reason

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm running Xubuntu on a laptop with 1366x768 resolution and Radeon 4330 card, default radeon driver. I've never made any manual config changes, everything ran smoothly for a couple of months after installing Xubuntu.

Suddenly after a system restart the resolution of display dropped to 1024x768 and `xrandr` output now says:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0:
minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768 default
connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1024x768    0.0*
```

So it now calls the output "default" and the only available resolution is wrong.

Before the problem occurred, `xrandr` output used to contain "LVDS" with a list of correct resolutions.

I did not make any configuration changes or install any new software lately.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.13.0
```

Turned out drivers stopped loading for display and some other devices. I noticed it and tried to reload the module

```
modprobe -r atl1c
modprobe atl1c
```

but it gave the following error

```
 modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/modules.dep.bin'
```

I investigated that, and found this question with the solution

["Could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.XX-generic/modules.dep.bin'" when mounting using a loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459296/could-not-open-moddep-file-lib-modules-3-xx-generic-modules-dep-bin-when-mo)

this solution also installed a pile of old kernels which I had to delete afterwards, but it worked