# Brother DCP-J4120DW will not print on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04

Brother Printer DCP-J4120DW will not print.

Ubuntu on Acer 5120. Brother driver originally loaded from supplied CDROM (windows and MAC) via WINE.

Apparently loaded OK - icons appeared on desktop, and printer recognised as present when using print command. However will not print. Also functionality of Brother Control Center limited. Suspected this could be due to incomplete driver load via WINE.

Downloaded Linux drivers from Brother web site - loaded OK but still wont print(or scan).

Comment: Did you uninstall the WINE driver? You probably should. Native Linux should work best. Can you provide the link you used to download the Linux drivers and describe how you installed them? Does the printer show up in your printer settings?

Comment: Have you tried using the built in Ubuntu drivers?

Answer (score 2):

Test this:

Download this files:

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf101555/dcpj4120dwlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf101556/dcpj4120dwcupswrapper-3.0.1-1.i386.deb

Install the drivers:

Turn on the printer and connect the usb, network or parallel cable.

Go to the directory where the drivers are.

In a terminal

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

run:

```
sudo -i

dpkg -i --force-all dcpj4120dwlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb

dpkg -i --force-all dcpj4120dwcupswrapper-3.0.1-1.i386.deb
```

Depending on the connection type you are using USB or Network, follow one of the steps below.

### For USB Connection:

```
Open a web browser and go to "http://localhost:631/printers".

Check if the Device URI of your printer is "usb://Brother/(your printer's model name)"

If the device URI is different from the example above, please go to "Modify Printer" of your printer to select proper device and driver.

If your printer is not listed on "http://localhost:631/printers", please go to "http://localhost:631/admin" and click "Add printer" and select proper device and driver.
```

### For Network Connection:

```
Open a web browser and go to "http://localhost:631/printers".

Click "Modify Printer" and set following parameters.

"LPD/LPR Host or Printer" or "AppSocket/HP JetDirect"       for Device

lpd://(Your printer's IP address)/binary_p1                 for Device URI

Brother                         for Make/Manufacturer Selection

Your printer's name             for Model/Driver Selection
```

### For Scanner driver 32bit:

Download this files:

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006646/brscan4-0.4.3-0.i386.deb

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006651/brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.i386.deb

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006654/brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb

Install the drivers:

Go to the directory where the drivers are.

In a terminal

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

run:

```
sudo -i

dpkg -i --force-all brscan4-0.4.3-0.i386.deb

dpkg -i --force-all brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.i386.deb

dpkg -i brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb
```

### For Scanner driver 64 bit:

Download this files:

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006645/brscan4-0.4.3-0.amd64.deb

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006652/brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006654/brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb

Install the drivers:

Go to the directory where the drivers are.

In a terminal

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

run:

```
sudo -i

dpkg -i --force-all brscan4-0.4.3-0.amd64.deb

dpkg -i --force-all brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb

dpkg -i brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what interface you are using. I only know that I had a problem yesterday with printing to my parallel port printer after my 1st ever install of Ubuntu (version 14.04 although the iso was for 14.02). The modules (lp, parport_pc, ppdev)  for the parallel interface were not being loaded at boot:
   'dmesg | grep parport'  ; 'dmesg | grep lp'  ; 'dmesg | grep ppdev'
all gave no reply as did similar greps on the output of 'lsmod".
Also /etc/modules only contained 'lp', and not 'parport_pc' and 'ppdev' as would be expected. Adding these to /etc/modules:
    # /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
 
    ppdev 
    lp 
    parport_pc

and rebooting did not solve the problem, but I left them there and tried manual install of the modules:
      modprobe par_port_pc ppdev
which gave an error report thus:-
   "modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not   open moddep"
From the last part of
 “["Could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.XX-generic/modules.dep.bin'" when mounting using a loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459296/could-not-open-moddep-file-lib-modules-3-xx-generic-modules-dep-bin-when-mo)”
I ran 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.13.0
rebooted and the modules were loaded and I installed the printer from cups (htt://localhost:631): it now found the printer automatically where it hadn't before.